# How to use a FOR loop in the main Method

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I cant seem to figure out how to make a for loop, so after they do the addition (1), it will go back to the menu. I need to use a for loop to do this also.

I cut out the rest of the code to save space. So I just need help on the Addition and I can do the rest.
(I never used this site, so I dont know how to post code correctly.)

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


    int add, add2, sub, sub2, multi, multi2, divi, divi2, rema, rema2, power, power2, Conf;
    System.out.println("(1) Addition~");
    System.out.println("(2) Subtraction~");
    System.out.println("(3) Multiply~");
    System.out.println("(4) Divide~");
    System.out.println("(5) Remainder~");
    System.out.println("(6) Power~");
    System.out.println("(7) Quit~");
    Conf = userInput.nextInt();

    if(Conf == 1)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter first number to add: ");
        add = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number to add: ");
        add2 = userInput.nextInt();
        Ansr();
        Adder(add, add2);

        Sp();
        }


    else if(Conf == 7);
    System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
        System.exit(0);
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly very confused by what you actually want. What's the problem? What do you want the code to do? What is it doing?

Comment: I think `while` loop will be more appropriate. Something like `while (Conf != 7)`. Initialize `Conf = 0` and then put everything after variable declarations and initialization inside such loop.

Comment: And `switch` will be easier to read then multiple `if - else` constructs.

Comment: I'd probably add some sort of function to do the problems. They're all likely doing the same things: Printing 2 lines asking for input, taking in 2 numbers as input, and performing a single operation. Edit: To clarify, I'd use a switch statement on `Conf` for 1 to 6 that calls some `doMath()` function, with a parameter specifying the math type.

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs a bit more clarity like why do you need a for loop for addition.

A while loop would be syntactically a better choice in this case.

Try this:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int add, add2, sub, sub2, multi, multi2, divi, divi2, rema, rema2, power, power2, Conf;

    Conf = 0;

    while(Conf != 7)
    {
       System.out.println("(1) Addition~");
       System.out.println("(2) Subtraction~");
       System.out.println("(3) Multiply~");
       System.out.println("(4) Divide~");
       System.out.println("(5) Remainder~");
       System.out.println("(6) Power~");
       System.out.println("(7) Quit~");

       Conf = userInput.nextInt();

       if(Conf == 1)
       {

           System.out.print("Enter first number to add: ");
           add = userInput.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Enter second number to add: ");
           add2 = userInput.nextInt();
           Ansr();
           Adder(add, add2);

           ............
       }
       else if()
       {
            // add additional else if for other operations
       }
    }

    userInput.close();
}
```

Comment: The **first** `Conf = userInput.nextInt();` will *eat* the first number. `Conf = 0` is much cleaner.

Comment: Remove `Conf = userInput.nextInt();` at the bottom.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: `for` and `while` loops can be used interchangeably. Your reasoning that `for` should be used "*only when you know the number of finite times the loop is going to run*" is inaccurate. I do agree that in this case `while` will be more obvious.